# Version code 1: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Email Address

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Issue found: Invalid Data safety form
We reviewed your app’s Data safety form in Play Console and found discrepancies between it and how the app collects and shares user data. All apps are required to complete an accurate Data safety form that discloses their data collection and sharing practices - this is required even if your app does not collect any user data.

We detected user data transmitted off device that you have not disclosed in your app’s Data safety form as user data collected.

You must ensure that your app’s Data safety section accurately reflects your app’s data collection, sharing, and handling practices. This includes data collected and handled through any third-party libraries or SDKs used in your app. When available, we’ve included details on SDKs that contain code similar to the code in your APK that may be sending user data off device. You can check if your app uses any of these SDKs, but note that this list of SDKs may not be exhaustive. You must review and account for all data collected and shared by your app.

Issue details

We found an issue in the following area(s):

Version code 1: Policy Declaration - Data Safety Section: Personal Info Data Type - Email Address
About the Data safety section in Google Play User Data policy
Your app must be in compliance with this policy. If your app continues to be non-compliant, your app updates will be rejected and your app may face additional enforcement actions in the future.

Please make changes to align your app’s Data safety form with the app’s behavior. This can be done by either:

Updating your form in Play Console to declare collection of Data Types noted below; or
Removing unwanted functionality and attributable code that collects this user data from your app or libraries used in your app, and when applicable to deactivate all non-compliant APKs.
To deactivate non-compliant APKS, you can create a new release and upload a compliant APK to each track containing the non-compliant APKs.
Be sure to increment the APK version code. If using staged rollout, be sure to set the release to 100% rollout.
For helpful resources, you can:

Learn more about how to provide app privacy and security information for Google Play's Data safety section.
Watch the Google Play PolicyBytes - Data safety form walkthrough.
Check Google Play SDK Index to see if your SDK provider has shared a link to their data safety guidance. Review how any third-party code (such as third-party libraries or SDKs) in your app collects and shares user data.

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/0uyA2.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.